# Photos album disappeared

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, photo-stream, software

I am using iPhone 5 (32GB) updated to iOS 8.1.2. 
Recently I opened the Photos app and saw that my all albums are gone but the photos are still visible in Moments.

[image]

I checked my iPhone Usage section but found out that my photos are on iPhone with space taken of 2.2GB.

[image]

I had all photos on my iPhone before sometime but after sometime all my photos were disappeared.

I have tried to force close the photos app, hard reset the device but non of them worked for me. I need some solution to this problem because it is really frustrating.

Comment: Did you enable iCloud Photo Library beta by any chance?

Comment: Yes 1 time I did enabled it by mistake and then quickly closed it. Today I restored it to factory setting and camera roll appeared but when I restored the backup all the albums again disappeared. What should I do I am stuck in the problem,

Comment: I have disabled it but no luck all the albums are still mising

Comment: If I check the albums though other software such as "Syncios" all the albums are present there as I grouped them.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve this problem is to completely backup all the data of phone from iTunes and 3rd party software's such as "Syncios" etc. You may use Cloud storage to save all your photos to them but not to iCloud. Now you would need to restore the phone from iTunes so that every file get refreshed. This will finish all the data now by turning on cloud services you can store your photos back to Camera Roll and they would work as it need to work. Contacts can also be brought back by iCloud or syncing from iTunes.

**Do not restore backup from iTunes or iCloud as it has all problems**

**You can get Game scores from Game center but be carefull I was not able to get my Temple Run 2 gems and score back on phone but my record in on Gamecenter.**
**You would now do a fresh backup of iPhone using iTunes or iCloud but don't restore previous one**

**Now its up to you wether you continue using your phone as it is or solve the problem by this way.** **Try to avoid using icloud photos if you don't know much about it because it was the root cause of my problem**

Any future queries I would be willing to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on home botton to open multitask operarions then shut down the page related to the photos application then re open the photos app and you will see your albums.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your phone on and off!!
It worked for mine !!

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Did you do a hard reset?  What new behavior did you observe after restarting your phone?

Answer (score -1):

Deplete your phone's battery to 0% then wait 10 minutes before charging it. Once it turns on check to see if your albums are back.